How to conceptually explain diagonal elements of viscous stress tensor in a fluid?
How can the diagonal components of viscosity tensor be explained conceptually? In other words, how can viscosity affect the normal stress (pressure) on the cube element of the fluid?
$$\sigma_{ii} = 2\mu  \epsilon_{ii}$$
where $$\mu$$ is viscosity and $$\sum\epsilon_{ii}$$ represents volumetric strain rate. What does viscousity have to do with this?

Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/617126/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/413140/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/79639/226902

See Transport Phenomena by Bird et al, Chapter 1 for the full derivation of the viscous stress components.
